# Python: Rename External Hard Drive Disk

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the function `win32api.GetVolumeInformation(path)` to get the information about my external driver disk. And I need to change the name of the hard disk using python. Any suggestions?

below is the code

```
import win32api

DiskInfo=win32api.GetVolumeInformation("E:\\")
print("DiskName:", DiskInfo[0])

## Output: DiskName: Musaab_Disk1
## My disk Name is "Musaab_Disk1", suppose I need to rename it to "Musaab_Disk2"??????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Dos command "label" by spawning a child process

```
import subprocess
import win32api

disk_info_old = win32api.GetVolumeInformation("E:\\")
print("disk info old", disk_info_old)

subprocess.run(['label', 'E:Musaab_Disk2'])
disk_info_new = win32api.GetVolumeInformation("E:\\")
print("disk info new", disk_info_new)
```

Comment: Thank you Yahya. It works, however I needed to change ".run" to ".call" in my version of python.